# resizing the jdialogbox in netbeans

Tags: java, resize, jdialog, netbeans-6.9

I've created an application in Netbeans IDE 6.9. I've different sizes of most of the dialog boxes. But when i run the application, all my dialog boxes have the same size and that size is that of the biggest dialog box.In the eye preview button i get different sizes, only when I run the application I get the same big size. Can anyone suggest what the problem maybe?
And is there any way in which the dialog box are sized automatically,i.e. I should not specify the size, the dialog boxes should adjust their sizes accordingly.
-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Open the design view.

2.Right click on the JDialog Form and select Properties.

3.In the properties select properties tab.

4.In the other  properties uncheck the "resizable" check box and in Preffered Size give the size you want.

5.Now clean & rebuild the project.
--It will work.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Generate Resize Code]

If you want to have total control on your desired size, do not use **pack()**

Use the following setting in the screen.